# Jest Mocking node_modules With Nested File

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to mock a 3rd party library (in node_modules) that is nested in a sub-directory.
I have created the mock in `__mocks__/@exponent/ex-navigation`. This sits at the top level next to my node_modules dir.

I setup the mock within my test file via `jest.mock('@exponent/ex-navigation');`.

For some reason I can't get it to use the mock file. I think it has something to do with the `@exponent` subdirectory. If I change it to something simple like `fs` it works.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Strangely this is not currently supported by Jest. Show your support for this feature request here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/462

Answer (score 8):

It appears that jest does not support mocking scoped packages (more info [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/462)). So you have two options.

**1. Define your mock inline**

```
jest.mock('@exponent/ex-navigation', () => {
  return {
    // mocked exports
  };
});
```

**2. Manually map the mock location in your jest config**

```
{
  ...
  "moduleNameMapper": [
    "@exponent/ex-navigation": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/@exponent/ex-navigation"
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I just had to assign my mock's exports to the `module.export` of step 1. => Didn't have to use `jest.mock()`

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Alex's answer, I succeeded by:

1. Setting up the mock at the top of my test suite

`jest.setMock('@exponent/ex-navigation', require('__mocks__/db'));`

2. Have the mock file export its mocked object thru `module.exports`

`module.exports = myMockedObject;`

Setting up mocks this way has the benefits of:

- not having to change jest settings;
- enable the "Orta.vscode-jest" extension to still be able to run the tests properly in the Visual Studio Code editor.